# Why is the voltage drop over my MOSFET so large?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, power-electronics, powermosfet, voltage

I am trying to use an [NCV8403B N-channel power MOSFET](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncv8403-d.pdf) to control the power for my circuit.

The schematic itself is quite simple:

[image]

The MOSFET is controlled by an SPST switch. When in the ON position, Vds and Vgs will be between 7V and 8.4V, depending on how charged the batteries are.

The Vgd is well above the Vgs(th)(gate threshold) of 1.0V-2.2V.

A Vgd of 7V - 8.4V should also give a Rds(on) value of about 40mOhms. With a current, Id, of 3A, that should equal a voltage drop of 0.12V, but when I test the circuit I get a voltage drop of 1.8V over the MOSFET.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Look up high-side drive. You have a source follower. MOSFETs are NOT controlled by the gate voltage. They are controlled by the voltage DIFFERENCE between gate and source. How is your MOSFET supposed to know what the voltage at GND is when none of its pins are connected to GND? Yet, you are applying a gate voltage relative to GND. What happens to the voltage at source node when current tries to flow through the load? What does this do to Vgs? Expect a lot of work providing 100% duty capable high-side drive for an NMOS. Bootstrap cap drive won't provide 100% duty. PMOS is easier in this respect

Comment: So, what I should do is connect the load before the mosfet, and have the source connected directly to the ground?

Comment: For PMOS it is simplest to +V (high-side). For an NMOS, it is simplest to connect closest to GND (low-side). But interrupting the GND can cause noise issues in some circuits so is not generally desirable but not a deal breaker either Works fine for simple things like heaters, LEDs, relays and sometimes motors but could run into issues with more sensitive or complex loads. Recommend you use PMOS on high-side instead.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. NMOS are bad for high-drive, but good for low-dive because they function based on the voltage difference between the Gate and Source, ad therefor needs to have a reliable voltage reference connected to the Source, which can easily be done by connecting the source to ground.

Comment: Not bad, but definitely more complex. NMOS are more efficient, after all. Otherwise, yes.

Comment: I definitely learned something new today. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a source follower, not high-side switch. MOSFETs are NOT controlled by the gate voltage. They are controlled by the voltage DIFFERENCE between gate and source. How is your MOSFET supposed to know what the voltage at GND is when none of its pins are connected to GND? Yet, you are applying a gate voltage relative to GND. What happens to the voltage at source node when current tries to flow through the load? What does this do to Vgs?

To use an NMOS in this situtation, you need what is called a "high-side gate drive" that drives the gate voltage relative to the source voltage, rather than relative to GND. But not just any high-side gate drive. Since yours is a switch, you require a high-side gate drive capable of 100% duty cycle which most high-side gate drives cannot do (motor and inverter commutation, for example alternates frequently between switches and does not need 100% duty cycle). Expect a lot of work providing 100% duty capable high-side drive for an NMOS. Bootstrap cap drive won't provide 100% duty. PMOS is easier in this respect.

For PMOS it is simplest to +V (high-side). For an NMOS, it is simplest to connect closest to GND (low-side). But interrupting the GND can cause noise issues in some circuits so is not generally desirable but not a deal breaker either Works fine for simple things like heaters, LEDs, relays and sometimes motors but could run into issues with more sensitive or complex loads. Recommend you use PMOS on high-side instead unless your current demands are so high you are forced to go with an NMOS.

NMOS on the high-side is not necessarily worse than PMOS; NMOS is more efficient after all, but it will definitely add complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit as it appears now has a couple minor issues.

SPST has 4 pins and appears to be a DPST or SPDT with a LED?

Vgs must be 2.5 to 3x Vgs(th) max.for low RdsOn.

Yet Vg=Vd=~Vs so Vgs =0 assuming V+ is common.

No go. Vs must be grounded at Vbat- with Vd to low side load to pull down.
(Assuming your interfaces can tolerate this in the off condition.)